# How do I convert a date/time string into a different date string?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How will I convert this datetime from the date?

> From this: 2016-02-29 12:24:26
>    **to: Feb 29, 2016**

So far, this is my code and it returns a nil value:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let date: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2016-02-29 12:24:26")
print(date)
```

Comment: Any one looking for another date formats check [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#8-date-format-patterns)

Answer (score 398, accepted):

You have to declare 2 different `NSDateFormatters`, the first to convert the string to a `NSDate` and the second to print the date in your format.
Try this code:

```
let dateFormatterGet = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateFormatterPrint = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

let date: NSDate? = dateFormatterGet.dateFromString("2016-02-29 12:24:26")
print(dateFormatterPrint.stringFromDate(date!))
```

**Swift 3 and higher:**

From Swift 3 `NSDate` class has been changed to `Date` and `NSDateFormatter` to `DateFormatter`.

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "2016-02-29 12:24:26") {
    print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date))
} else {
   print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

Comment: What happens if the dateFormatterGet dateFormat needs to accept 2 different formats - one containing milliseconds and one without milliseconds? ie yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ and yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZZZZZ

Comment: I think you have to declare two different DateFormatters to get the date: if the first one fails (it will return nil), use the second.

Comment: Can you please help me, what will the date format for "Tue Mar 12 2019 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)"

Comment: @Devesh it should be something like this "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ", check out https://nsdateformatter.com it's a very hanful site with all the formats supported

Comment: @lorenzoliveto yes I have tried all the way for this format I tried on nsdateformatter.com too, still, I am not able to get anything for "Tue Mar 12 2019 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)"  this format. I am getting this format in a JSON. I am not sure wether this is valid string, can you please help me.

Comment: @Devesh this should be the format you need "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('z')'"

Comment: @Devesh E MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z will work for you

Answer (score 594):

This may be useful for who want to use `dateformatter.dateformat`;

if you want `12.09.18` you use `dateformatter.dateformat = "dd.MM.yy"`

```
Wednesday, Sep 12, 2018           --> EEEE, MMM d, yyyy
09/12/2018                        --> MM/dd/yyyy
09-12-2018 14:11                  --> MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm
Sep 12, 2:11 PM                   --> MMM d, h:mm a
September 2018                    --> MMMM yyyy
Sep 12, 2018                      --> MMM d, yyyy
Wed, 12 Sep 2018 14:11:54 +0000   --> E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
2018-09-12T14:11:54+0000          --> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
12.09.18                          --> dd.MM.yy
10:41:02.112                      --> HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Here are alternatives:

- Era: G (AD), GGGG (Anno Domini)
- Year: y (2018), yy (18), yyyy (2018)
- Month: M, MM, MMM, MMMM, MMMMM
- Day of month: d, dd
- Day name of week: E, EEEE, EEEEE, EEEEEE

Comment: One of the best answer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093100/1663987 for how to get the whole list.

Comment: I just run into one thing that might be useful for someone some day: there is an important difference between "YYYY" and "yyyy" dateFormats. "YYYY" will respect the year the week started at of the date: Jan 1, 2022 will actually display Jan 1, 2021 because that week started in 2021. This can be rather annoying to spot. Use "yyyy" as it is in this post. "YYYY" sounds to be useful in a particular scenario when you need to display the year the week started at as opposed to the actual year belongs to the date.

Comment: Any one looking for another date formats check [this](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#8-date-format-patterns)

Comment: This doesn't make any attempt to answer the question. This is just a list of example date formats. The question is asking how to convert a string from one format to another.

Answer (score 101):

### Swift - 5.0

```
let date = Date()
let format = date.getFormattedDate(format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") // Set output format

extension Date {
   func getFormattedDate(format: String) -> String {
        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateFormat = format
        return dateformat.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

### Swift - 4.0

**2018-02-01T19:10:04+00:00** Convert **Feb 01,2018**

```
extension Date {
    static func getFormattedDate(string: String , formatter:String) -> String{
        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        
        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
        
        let date: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "2018-02-01T19:10:04+00:00")
        print("Date",dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!)) // Feb 01,2018
        return dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date!);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 70):

### Swift 3 and higher

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // Jan 2, 2001
```

This is also helpful when you want to localize your App. The Locale(identifier: ) uses the [ISO 639-1 Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html).
See also the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Comment: If you want to localize your app, just use `Locale.current` to use the user's locale.

Answer (score 37):

**Swift 3** version with the new `Date` object instead `NSDate`:

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

let date: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "2017-02-14 17:24:26")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))
```

EDIT: after [mitul-nakum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252037/mitul-nakum) suggestion

Comment: dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" hour formate will require capital HH, as hour is in 24 formate

Answer (score 34):

Convert @BatyrCan answer to Swift 5.3 with extra formats. Tested in Xcode 12.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
var dateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from: "12:16:45")!

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
//Output: 12:16:45 PM on January 01, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
//Output: Sat, 1 Jan 2000 12:16:45 +0600

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
//Output: 2000-01-01T12:16:45+0600

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
//Output: Saturday, Jan 1, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
//Output: 01-01-2000 12:16

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
//Output: Jan 1, 12:16 PM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
//Output: 12:16:45.000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
//Output: Jan 1, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
//Output: 01/01/2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
//Output: 12:16:45 PM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
//Output: January 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
//Output: 01.01.00

//Customisable AP/PM symbols
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "Pm"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "a"
//Output: Pm

// Usage
var timeFromDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
print(timeFromDate)
```

Answer (score 33):

I solved my problem to the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`(e.g 2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z) with this:

```
func formatDate(date: String) -> String {
   let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
   dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
   //    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US") //uncomment if you don't want to get the system default format.

   let dateObj: Date? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: date)

   return dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
}
```

Answer (score 30):

**swift 3**

```
let date : Date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
let todaysDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Answer (score 22):

## iOS 15.0+

iPadOS 15.0+,

macOS 12.0+,

Mac Catalyst 15.0+,

tvOS 15.0+,

watchOS 8.0+,

Xcode 13.0+

Use `formatted(date:time:)`

```
let now = Date.now
let date = now.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)
```

Instead of `.abbreviated`, you may use another `DateStyle` such as `.long`, `.numeric` or define a custom format.

---

#### SwiftUI

```
 Text(myDate, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .omitted))
```

or simply use:

```
 Text(myDate, style: .date)
```

#### Reference

[formatted(date:time:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/3766588-formatted)

[init(_:format:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:))

[Text.DateStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/datestyle)

Comment: The documentation says this is available in iOS 15, not related to Swift version.

Comment: This is the best new way according to [the WWDC 2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10109/?time=871)! **If you want to have more flexibility you can use `.dateTime` inside `.formatted()`** instead of the `.formatted(date:time:)`. For example `.formatted(.dateTime.day().month())` will get you „Feb 29“. Check out the [Date.FormatStyle documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle) for more details.

Answer (score 15):

### Swift Version: 5.6 + Above

[DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)’s dateFormatter property is used to format Date with a custom String Pattern.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
    
let date = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
print(date)
//Feb 28, 2022
```

If you want anything that shouldn’t be formatted and printed, then use single quotes around that word. Like; `‘at’`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:MM a"
// May 29, 2022 at 12:05 PM
```

These are all possible **Patterns** to Format `Date`, `Time` & `Time Zone`.

[image]

Comment: not really, some put a "T" in before the time, not sure how that works.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4, 4.2 and 5**

```
func getFormattedDate(date: Date, format: String) -> String {
        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateFormat = format
        return dateformat.string(from: date)
}

let formatingDate = getFormattedDate(date: Date(), format: "dd-MMM-yyyy")
        print(formatingDate)
```

Comment: This is a good, short solution with just a single `DateFormatter()`! Something to be aware of: The `DateFormatter` also takes the application region (set in the scheme) into account! E.g. `2019-05-27 11:03:03 +0000` with the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and "Germany" as the region turns into `2019-05-27 13:03:03`. This difference is caused by DST: In summer Germany is GMT+2, while in winter it's GMT+1.

Comment: Superb answer! Good job.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3 with a `Date` extension

```
extension Date {
    func string(with format: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
let date = Date()
date.string(with: "MMM dd, yyyy")
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to parse date from "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00", use the following format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ":

```
let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

/* 39 minutes and 57 seconds after the 16th hour of December 19th, 1996 with an offset of -08:00 from UTC (Pacific Standard Time) */
let string = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
let date = RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

from Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Answer (score 5):

Another interessant possibility of format date. This screenshot belongs to Apple's App "News".

[image: App screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
let dateFormat1 = DateFormatter()
dateFormat1.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let stringDay = dateFormat1.string(from: Date())

let dateFormat2 = DateFormatter()
dateFormat2.dateFormat = "MMMM"
let stringMonth = dateFormat2.string(from: Date())

let dateFormat3 = DateFormatter()
dateFormat3.dateFormat = "dd"
let numDay = dateFormat3.string(from: Date())

let stringDate = String(format: "%@\n%@ %@", stringDay.uppercased(), stringMonth.uppercased(), numDay)
```

**Nothing to add to alternative proposed by lorenzoliveto. It's just perfect.**

```
let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "EEEE\nMMMM dd"
let stringDate = dateFormat.string(from: Date()).uppercased()
```

Comment: This can be compacted using only one date formatter with the format "EEEE\nMMMM dd".

Comment: RECTIFICATION: I have tested the code but you do not obtain the letters in uppercase.

Comment: Yes, the uppercase has to be applied to the string returned, like in your answer. The the date formatter doesn't return an uppercase string. Just add .uppercased() like this "dateFormat.string(from: Date()).uppercased()"

Answer (score 5):

```
    import UIKit
    // Example iso date time
    let isoDateArray = [
        "2020-03-18T07:32:39.88Z",
        "2020-03-18T07:32:39Z",
        "2020-03-18T07:32:39.8Z",
        "2020-03-18T07:32:39.88Z",
        "2020-03-18T07:32:39.8834Z"
    ]


    let dateFormatterGetWithMs = DateFormatter()
    let dateFormatterGetNoMs = DateFormatter()

// Formater with and without millisecond 
    dateFormatterGetWithMs.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    dateFormatterGetNoMs.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

    for dateString in isoDateArray {
        var date: Date? = dateFormatterGetWithMs.date(from: dateString)
        if (date == nil){
            date = dateFormatterGetNoMs.date(from: dateString)
        }
        print("===========>",date!)
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

just use below function to convert date format:-

```
  let convertedFormat =  convertToString(dateString: "2019-02-12 11:23:12", formatIn: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", formatOut: "MMM dd, yyyy")    //calling function

   print(convertedFormat) // feb 12 2019


 func convertToString (dateString: String, formatIn : String, formatOut : String) -> String {

    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    dateFormater.dateFormat = formatIn
    let date = dateFormater.date(from: dateString)

    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system

    dateFormater.dateFormat = formatOut
    let timeStr = dateFormater.string(from: date!)
    return timeStr
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert 2016-02-29 12:24:26 into a date, use this date formatter:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

Edit: To get the output Feb 29, 2016 use this date formatter:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
```

Comment: But how will you convert that to this kind of date format Feb 29, 2016

Comment: do you know why I get nil when I try to print this?

Answer (score 2):

Place it in extension and call it like below. It's easy to use throughout the application.

```
self.getFormattedDate(strDate: "20-March-2019", currentFomat: "dd-MMM-yyyy", expectedFromat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Implementation

```
func getFormattedDate(strDate: String , currentFomat:String, expectedFromat: String) -> String{
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = currentFomat

    let date : Date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: strDate) ?? Date()

    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = expectedFromat
    return dateFormatterGet.string(from: date)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 4.2, 5**

Pass date and format as whatever way you want. 
To choose format you can visit, [NSDATEFORMATTER website](https://nsdateformatter.com):

```
static func dateFormatter(date: Date,dateFormat:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 15 use something like this:

```
extension Date {
    var string: String {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            return self.formatted(date: .complete, time: .complete)
        } else {
            return self.description
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full date format extension for swift

```
extension Date {
   func getFormattedDate(format: String) -> String {
        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateFormat = format
        return dateformat.string(from: self)
    }
    
    func getFormattedDate(style: DateFormatter.Style) -> String {
         let dateformat = DateFormatter()
         dateformat.dateStyle = style
         return dateformat.string(from: self)
     }
}
```

Usage

```
myDate.getFormattedDate(style: .medium) //medium, short, full, long
```

OR

```
myDate.getFormattedDate(format: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
func dataFormat(dataJ: Double) -> String {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dataJ)
        return (dataJ != nil) ? "Today, \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))" : "Date Invalid"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add timezone by default. I will show an example for swift 5
1. new an extension file `Date+Formatter.swift`

```
import Foundation

extension Date {
    func getFormattedDateString(format: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

2. Usage example

```swift
    let date = Date()
    let dateString = date.getFormattedDateString(format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    print("dateString > \(dateString)")
    // print
    // dateString > 2020-04-30 15:15:21
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Date**

```
Date <-> Formatter <-> String
```

**Date**

Date:

- single point in time (UTC). It means that it doesn't contain any TimeZone or other metadata
- Is a kind of wrapper of `Double` - seconds from `2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000`

```
Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: .zero)
```

- print output of Date in UTC(+0000) is in ISO 8601(`ISO8601DateFormatter` `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`)

Create Date:

- current time in UTC `Date()`
- from String using Formatter and TimeZone

```
func strToDateWithLocalTimeZone(_ str: String, format: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
//        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current //by default
//        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    
    return dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
}
```

**Formatter**

It is responsible for formatting date and have two main functions:

- Date -> String: `.string(from: Date)`
- String -> Date: `.date(from: String)`

Main parts:

- Formatter.dateFormat

  - Custom: `yyyy-MM-dd`, `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss`...
  - `ISO8601DateFormatter`: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
- Formatter.TimeZone

  - `Formatter.TimeZone = .current` is set by default. It means if you don't setup it explicitly local TimeZone will be used by default
  - Local aka Current TimeZone is defined by System and your settings. Also it is different for specific Date. It means that when you use `Formatter.TimeZone.current` for Date with different time shift in time - value will be different(for current TimeZone). Fir example In my country we have two time shifts in a year, and TimeZone for specific date will reflect it

  ```
  //TimeZone in Settings
  Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Time Zone
  ```

  ```
  //Date -> String
  2022-12-31T22:59:59+02:00
  2023-04-04T21:01:34+03:00
  ```

  - Specific. `TimeZone(abbreviation: "CET") == TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 3600)` (3600 seconds == 1 hour). UTC. `TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")`...

**String**

- If String doesn't contain TimeZone you are able to set TimeZone in Formatter
- When String contains TimeZone - it means that it is a single variant of interpret the String in Date UTC that is why `Formatter.TimeZone` will not have any effect

```
String <date_with_time_zone> -> Format <any_time_zome> -> single Date
String: 09.04.2023T18:58:32+0300 -> Format <any_time_zome> -> Date: 2023-04-09 15:58:32 +0000
```

Experiments:

My Local time:

[image]

```
let dateFormatStr = "dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

//Current TimeZone
let currentTimeZone = TimeZone.current
let seconds = currentTimeZone.secondsFromGMT()
let hours = seconds/3600
let minutes = abs(seconds/60) % 60
print("current TimeZone: \(String(format: "%+.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes)) for:\(currentTimeZone)")
//        current TimeZone: +03:00 for:Europe/Kiev (fixed (equal to current))

//Current Date
let currentDate = Date()
print("current Date UTC: \(currentDate)")
//        current Date UTC: 2023-04-09 15:58:32 +0000

//Date -> String
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormatStr
dateFormatter.timeZone = .current //by default. Adds +0300 in my case at the end of string
let currentDateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
print("current DateString Local: \(currentDateStr)")
//        current DateString Local: 09.04.2023T18:58:32+0300

//String to Date
let dateFormatterLocal = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterLocal.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatterLocal.dateFormat = dateFormatStr
dateFormatterLocal.timeZone = .current //by default. Doesn't have effect when String contains TimeZone

let dateLocal = dateFormatterLocal.date(from: currentDateStr)!
print("current Date Local: \(dateLocal)")
//        current Date Local: 2023-04-09 15:58:32 +0000
```

Output in a single place

```
current TimeZone: +03:00 for:Europe/Kiev (fixed (equal to current))
current Date UTC: 2023-04-09 15:58:32 +0000
current DateString Local: 09.04.2023T18:58:32+0300
current Date Local: 2023-04-09 15:58:32 +0000
```

Some real use case:

1. Client make a transaction
2. Send Date to Server as String
3. Get Date from Server as String
4. Show Date as String in:

- UTC
- Local TimeZone
- Transaction TimeZone

```
1. Client make a transaction
Date()
Formatter.timeZone = .current
String: 09.04.2023 18:58:32+0300

2. Send Date to Server as String
09.04.2023 18:58:32+0300

3. Get Date from Server as String 
09.04.2023 18:58:32+0300

4. Show Date

- UTC TimeZone
String -> Date -> Formatter.timeZone = UTC -> String
UTC: 09.04.2023 15:58:32+0000

- Local TimeZone(Depends where you are)
String -> Date -> Formatter.timeZone = .current -> String
For example Local timezone will be different: 
    if you now at +0100 TimeZone 09.04.2023 16:58:32+0100
    if you now at +0200 TimeZone 09.04.2023 17:58:32+0200

- Transaction TimeZone
remove +0300 from String. It is a workaround, and not a clear solution but as is: 09.04.2023 18:58:32 

String -> Formatter.timeZone = UTC -> Date: 09.04.2023 18:58:32+0000
Date -> Formatter.timeZone = UTC -> String: 09.04.2023 18:58:32+0000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Utils {
  class func dateFormatter(_ date: Date, _ format: String) -> String {
    let dateformat = DateFormatter()
    dateformat.dateFormat = format
    return dateformat.string(from: date)
  }
}
print(Utils.dateFormatter(Date(), "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"))
```

Create class name Utils import same function and you can use globally accesss any where with your date and formate