# Using DateFormatter with TimeZone to format dates in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftdate

How can I parse a date that has only date information (without time), like `2018-07-24`

Im trying with

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-07-24")
```

> prints day 23

It looks like it uses `00:00:00` as default time and then transform it into UTC results into the day before...

How can I change that?

Comment: check this, may this help : [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Comment: Do you want the `2018-07-24` to be treated as midnight locale time to the user, midnight UTC, or midnight is some other timezone?

Comment: And where exactly do you see "23"?

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you set time zone for formatter to UTC but then try to get the day in your local time zone.

If you use this code - you will see the 24-th day

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-07-24")

print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!)) // prints "2018-07-24"
```

But if you use "Calendar" to get the day component from the date you will get the day with your timeZone offset.

So for example in my time zone I see the 24th day (GMT+02) using this code

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date!)
print(day) // prints 24
```

But if I set the time zone for calendar somewhere in USA I see the 23rd day

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "MDT")!
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date!)
print(day) // prints 23
```

So the calendar uses your local time zone to get the component from date

So if you need to get the day component from date use the same time zone you used to parse the date from string.

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date!)
print(day) // prints 24
```