# Date not being created from String with DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following date string:

```
let dateString = "2018-06-24T14:52:32.647Z"
```

I'm trying to turn it into a date. However, it's not working with my `DateFormatter`.

I have extended DateFormatter to give a static formatter that I use throughout my app:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Then I say:

```
let date = DateFormatter.formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

It returns `nil` on one of my devices, but works on the rest of them. What am I doing wrong? Is it because I have three `Z`s at the end and I should have one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43434964/5146460

Answer (score 1):

You need next date format:

```
extension DateFormatter {
static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    return formatter
}()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works in some device then it must be Language and Region problem.

Check In Setting -> General -> Language & Region, in which region working and which not.

Every region have different date formatter.

Comment: This is sort of the right answer. I wasn't using the 24-hour time setting on my iPhone. Adding a locale to my date formatter solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You send wrong format to formatter

You have to change this code

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"
```

with

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```