# How to change JSON string to date format in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm displaying JSON data using a tableView and I want to convert JSON string to date format in tableView cell.

My JSON date in string format:

```
"createdDate": "2018-08-16 11:34:59"
```

I want to convert it into date format
in `cellForRowAt` function.

```
struct JSONInfo: Decodable {
    let createdDate: String
}
```

In my `cellForRowAt` function:

```
cell.Date.text = JSONList[indexPath.row].createdDate

let createdDate = JSONlist[indexPath.row].createdDate
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: createdDate)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let IssuedDate = dateFormatter.string(from:date!)

let lastDate = JSONlist[indexPath.row].dueDate
let dateFormatters = DateFormatter()
dateFormatters.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatters.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatters.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let dates = dateFormatter.date(from: lastDate)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let DueDate = dateFormatter.string(from:dates!)
```

It's getting error in lastdate.
I get the error here:

```
let DueDate = dateFormatter.string(from:dates!)
```

Comment: use `DateFormatter`.

Comment: how can i use in cell for row func

Comment: can u show me in my code

Comment: In which format you need output?

Comment: i want in dd/mm/yyyy format and json data is in string and im also using protocol in string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Comment: You could change your struct to hold a `Date` object and use a `JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy` when decoding your json data, that way you would only need to format once, from Date to String, when showing the value in the cell.

Comment: The error means that `dates` is `nil`. And `dates` is `nil` because `lastDate` is not in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which format do you want to convert. Try this one with your desired format

```
if let dateString = JSONList[indexPath.row].createdDate{

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from:date!)

cell.Date.text = dateStr

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" //This formate is input formated .
let formateDate = dateFormatter.date(from:"2018-08-16 11:34:59")! //here will be your json string
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" // Output Formated
print ("Print :\(dateFormatter.string(from: formateDate))") // Print 16-08-2018
```

Comment: i'm getting eror like this Value of type 'String' has no member 'dateFormat

Comment: @user9772943 update your exact code and i wll fix it

Comment: @user9772943 and by the way my code is working in my project so u can just try with it :)

Comment: @user9772943 Answer is correct, might be you doing somethig wrong.

Comment: struct ChallanInfo: Decodable {
    
    let createdDate: String }

Comment: @user9772943 put your created date here in argument of this line "let formateDate = dateFormatter.date(from:"2018-08-16 11:34:59")!"

Comment: i have json date with created date and last date the code is working with created date and getting error in last date. its saying Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @user9772943 if it's working with created date then it should work with last date as well the only reason can be if ur data comes null or the last date format comes in diffrent format than created  date

Comment: @user9772943 print your last date and let me know how it looks

Comment: i cant print because its getting error like this Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from:date!) here gets error

Comment: @user9772943 check "date!" variable you must getting it nil it means your dateString coming wrong

Comment: yeah its getting nil but json im getting full format like this "2018-08-31 00:00:00"