# Cannot assign value of type 'CLong?' (aka 'Optional<Int>') to type 'String?' [Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Questions : **How do I use DateFormatter(Type: CLong) in tableview?**

Similar questions I looked for

[How to change JSON string to date format in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930265/how-to-change-json-string-to-date-format-in-tableview)

I looked up questions like these on stackoverflow. However, there was no way to use Type: CLong.

Clong is a type I'm new to using, so I don't know what type to use Optional.

**connection json file**

```
struct BoardList: Codable {
    var b_date: CLong?
}
```

**TableViewController**

```
var boards: [BoardList]?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
      if let boards = self.boards {
         let model = boards[indexPath.row]
            
         let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
         dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

         cell.txtDate.text = model.b_date // ERROR [Cannot assign value of type 'CLong?' (aka 'Optional<Int>') to type 'String?']
    
     }
     return cell
 }
```

++ I must take the CLong type. Because the server value is specified in that format.

**value assigned to Postman**
[image: value assigned to Postman]

Comment: Why are you using `C*` types in parsed types?

Comment: I just modified the question. Thank you - user28434

Comment: question still stands. In `Swift` `CLong` is just an alias for `Int`. And if server uses some type it doesn't mean at all the client should use the same type.

Comment: You need to know what the value in `b_date` represents; presumably seconds since some reference point. Once you know this you can use the Int value to create a `Date`

Comment: At first, I received that as a String and then received the error as an Int, and I was confused with the error. It works well even if I receive it as an Int. I think I should get the year/month/day here. Thank you for your answer.
I thought I should only get it with clong. Sorry -user28434, Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server sends JSON. There is no type `CLong` in JSON, it's an `Int`.

You can decode the date without any date formatter just be declaring `b_date` as `Date`. The default date decoding strategy is `secondsSince1970` which the integer represents.

```
let jsonString = """
{"b_date" : 1602813427}
"""

struct BoardList: Codable {
    let b_date: Date
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(BoardList.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can also specify the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy and declare the struct member `bDate` to get rid of the ugly snake case name.

Comment: Technically, there's no `Int` in `JSON` either. Only `Number` which is like `Double` in `Swift`. That's also the reason why `[U]Int64` may behave weird when parsed from `JSON`.

Comment: @user28434 Yes, but the `JSONDecoder` treats integer values as `Int` by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, vadian, but I can't specify a value because it only converts and loads multiple b_date values ​​from the server. What should I do in this case?

I have a lot of b_date values
ex) 1602813434,1602813474

Comment: `1602813434,1602813474` is invalid JSON unless the entire expression is wrapped in double quotes or in square brackets.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. I am doing a process that converts the value ```b_date``` that I put in in real time for practice on the server. The time will continue to change, but if you save it in a variable, I think that the newly registered values ​​cannot be time converted. - vadian

Comment: `"b_date": 1602813434,1602813474` in a JSON string is not valid. Valid JSON is `"b_date": "1602813434,1602813474"` or `"b_date": [1602813434,1602813474]`

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you.

The ```ex)1602813434,1602813474``` that I mentioned shows some of the values ​​stored in the server.

In the server, ```"b_date": 1602834691``` is stored like this

In xcode I have ```struct BoardList: Codable {
var b_date: Int?
}``` It is loaded in the form.

Servers have a lot of value. As I said before, I think that if I store the values ​​added in real time in an array, I cannot change all the added values ​​to the current time. The question is complicated, but I would really appreciate if you could answer it.

Comment: I should have summarized it well, but I'm sorry for the complexity.