# How to parse json with Decodable ?

Tags: swift, decodable

when i try to parse my json with decodable birthday comes nil.
What date format should I use any advice or code sample please.
my date format include timezone.

My problem is birthdate comes nil. How to parse birthdate with decodable ?

**My json :**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "fatih",
    "birddate": "2018-09-19T11:36:00.4033163+03:00",
    "total": 0.9,
    "isTest": false
}
```

**here is my struct :**

```
struct TestDTO : Decodable {
    var id:Int?
    var name : String?
    var birtdate : Date?
    var total : Double?
    var isTest : Bool?
}

RestClientServiceTest().CallRestService(matching: cmd, completion: { (data) in
            do{

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
                let stories = try decoder.decode(TestDTO.self, from: data!)
                print(data)
            }catch let error{
                print("Json Parse Error : \(error)")
            }
        })
```

Comment: Spelling!!: `birthday` != `birddate` != `birtdate`

Comment: I suggest you that parse birthdate as string, and add one instance method that convert string date to Date

Comment: Maybe `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Certainly not `YYYY-mm-DD` and not `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @vadian That's I'm going to bed

Comment: Can you add `dateFormatter` initialization code to the question? It is essential for solving your problem.

Answer (score 3):

So, having a bit of play in playground...

```
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
let value = "2018-09-19T11:36:00.4033163+03:00"
print(format.date(from: value))
```

Prints `2018-09-19 08:36:00 +0000`

So taking that a leap further...

```
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"

let text = """
{
"id": 1,
"name": "fatih",
"birddate": "2018-09-19T11:36:00.4033163+03:00",
"total": 0.9,
"isTest": false
}
"""

struct TestDTO : Decodable {
    var id:Int?
    var name : String?
    var birddate : Date?
    var total : Double?
    var isTest : Bool?
}

do{
    let jsonData = text.data(using: .utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(format)
    let stories = try decoder.decode(TestDTO.self, from: jsonData!)
    print(stories)
}catch let error{
    print("Json Parse Error : \(error)")
}
```

prints...

```
TestDTO(id: Optional(1), name: Optional("fatih"), birddate: Optional(2018-09-19 08:36:00 +0000), total: Optional(0.9), isTest: Optional(false))
```

You might find [Easy Skeezy Date Formatting for Swift](http://nsdateformatter.com) of some use

Comment: Can you also use `birthdate` instead of `birddate`(whatever it is)?

Comment: @user28434 You can use what every you want, I just took what was given and made it work - to tired of making assumptions, sorry

Comment: Well, as @vadian noticed, question uses 3 different forms, only `birthdate` looks like something.

Comment: @user28434 Your points are valid - but I just focused on getting the date format to work - the OP will need to fix any other inconsistencies - I appreciate this is probably going to annoy some people, about as much as people representing date/time values as strings in code does to me

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all the name you used in `struct` is wrong `birddate` - typo error.
2. Second don't set it as `Date` it's an `String`.

Get the data as `String` and while using it go with `NSDateFormatter`.

You can search for `NSDateFormatter` on SO.

- [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Comment: It is `Date` represented as `String`, `JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy.formatted()`(and `.iso8601`) exist exactly for this. To prevent you from doing it manually.

Comment: @user28434 : That I wasn't aware of. I was using `NSDateFormatter`. Thank you. Should I remove my answer ?