# Custom Repeat component like in the ios Calendar

Tags: ios, react-native, calendar

I have a react native project and I have a picker for a repeat event, I want to build it to be like a repeat event in native ios devices, so anyone can give me an idea of how to do it

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS how to set Alarm and schedule work/notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557046/ios-how-to-set-alarm-and-schedule-work-notifications)

Comment: no, i need this repeat screen from IOS into react-native, not an Alarm or notification system ,