# How can I format Date range to "MMM, d"?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display the week number of current date, and the date range of the week number. Right now the date range format is DateTime, I would like to change it to "Jan 13"instead. Any recommendations on how I can fix this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let dateToday = Date()
    let weekNumber = NSCalendar.current.component(.weekOfYear, from: dateToday)
    let weekRange = dayRangeOf(weekOfYear: weekNumber, for: dateToday)

    weekLabel.text = String("Week #\(weekNumber): \(weekRange)")
}

func dayRangeOf(weekOfYear: Int, for date: Date) -> Range<Date>
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let year = calendar.component(.yearForWeekOfYear, from: date)
    let startComponents = DateComponents(weekOfYear: weekOfYear, yearForWeekOfYear: year)
    let startDate = calendar.date(from: startComponents)!
    let endComponents = DateComponents(day:7, second: -1)
    let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: endComponents, to: startDate)!
    return startDate..<endDate
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what input you are providing, the output your are currently getting, and the exact output you actually want. `"mm, d"` is not a date range. A string such as `Jan 13` is not in the format `mm, d`. `MMM d` would give `Jan 13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated API to display date intervals: [`DateIntervalFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateintervalformatter)

```
let intervalForatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
intervalFormatter.timeStyle = .none
intervalFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
weekLabel.text = String("Week #\(weekNumber): \(intervalFormatter.string(from: weekRange.lowerBound, to: weekRange.upperBound))")
```

You can also use a custom date format (by the way Jan 13 is `MMM d`)

```
let intervalFormatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
intervalFormatter.dateTemplate = "MMM d"
let text = String("Week #\(weekNumber): \(intervalFormatter.string(from: weekRange.lowerBound, to: weekRange.upperBound))")
```

Comment: I used the custom date format, this totally worked. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can user answer from: 
[Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MM d"

if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "2016-02-29 12:24:26") {
    print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date))
} else {
   print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

Comment: The OP says they want 3 letter month names. That would be a format of "MMM d", wouldn't it?\

Comment: You can use any format, use https://nsdateformatter.com to get the format you want.

Comment: My point is that the OP was asking for a specific output format, and I don't think your answer provides that format. I don't use date formats often enough to have them memorized, but i seem to remember that 3 letter month names use the `MMM` format code.

Comment: @DuncanC like i said before you can use nsdateformatter.com to get right format. It provide all variations of date to you. If you need Jan, 01... use "MMM, dd"