# ios Swift Date without Time

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get only date that means hours, mins, seconds are zeroes. This is what i am trying

```
extension Date {

    var onlyDate: Date? {
        get {
            let calender = Calendar.current
            var dateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
            dateComponents.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
            return calender.date(from: dateComponents)
        }
    }

}
```

When i try

```
date = Date().onlyDate
```

[image: My Output]

It returns the previous date. You can check the screenshot that its giving me 14th April while it should have been 15th

Comment: please check this same Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift

Comment: For a “timeless” date you should use noon instead of midnight

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me guess, you are in the GMT+6 time zone, aren't you?

**When `Date`s are printed, they always show up in UTC.**

2019-04-14 18:00 UTC ***is the same as*** 2019-04-15 00:00 in your local time zone.

Your code is not wrong. It works fine.

To see it in your time zone, use a `DateFormatter` and set the `timeZone` property:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .none
formatter.dateStyle = .full
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
print(formatter.string(from: Date().onlyDate))
```

Comment: will it work with date? 
formatter.date(from: yourDate) will not work

Comment: What do you mean? Note that a `Date` is just a point in time. `2019-04-14 18:00 UTC` is the same point in time as `2019-04-15 00:00 GMT+6`. You don't need to change anything about your `Date` object. You just need to change your way of displaying the date. @dineshsharma

Comment: extension Date {

    var onlyDate: Date {
        get {
            let calender = Calendar.current
            var dateComponents = calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd"
            let date = calender.date(from: dateComponents)
            let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
            print(stringDate)
            print(dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate))
            return dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!

        }
    }
}

Comment: you can run it by:- let date = Date().onlyDate line. please try it

Comment: No you don't need to change anything in the extension.Your extension is correct. The `date` object you get from `Date().onlyDate` is correct. The thing that's wrong is how you display it. See the edit. @dineshsharma

Comment: Now i got the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Date is a point in time. Making some of its components zero can only work in conjunction with given time zone, calendar.

What you did looks correctly. But the problem is how your debugger shows date. It again needs to use a certain time zone, calendar which probably matches to what you have on your computer (or device).

To make more sense let's say I am using UTC but am debugging this in -1. Then if I create a date `15.4.2019 at 0:00:00` but debug it I will see `14.4.2019 at 23:00:00`.

So `Date` itself is let's say not human readable. Underneath is I believe a double precision floating value counting seconds from EPOCH 1.1.1970 UTC. You need to apply a calendar and time zone to `Date` instance and use formatter to convert it to something that you can read (as in `14.4.2019 at 23:00:00` is readable). And if the calendars or time zones are not the same then the results will not be the same. Because at some point `14.4.2019 at 23:00:00` and `15.4.2019 at 0:00:00` were exactly the same moment for 2 different locations on earth.