# Displaying system date as dd MMM

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently working on a swift project in Xcode.

I am trying to display the system date from the users device in the format of dd  MMM.

I currently have

```
dateLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.medium, timeStyle:DateFormatter.Style.none)
```

this is outputting a MMM dd, YYYY to the display,

is there anyway to output this as dd MMM.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DateFormatter Class
and set any valid format  for output:

```
let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, YYYY"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        print(stringDate)
```

for more detail:
[Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)