# Can't converting String to NSDate Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
 func createDatePicker() {
    datePicker?.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
    dateTextField.inputView = datePicker
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = createToolBar()
}

@objc func donePressed() {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

    self.dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker!.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

This code is in firstViewController for datePicker, and in the secondViewController I have this error.
I want to make counting down days from today to date selected with picker.[image]

Comment: The date format most likely does not match the date string being passed in.

Comment: You crash on `date(from:)` and show only the code of `.string(from:)`. We don't know how liiks like `dateOfEvent`, and the formatter use has no format?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

dateFormatter.dateFormat should match the date string you are passing.

check this [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @m_k_s It works now, but in label is displaying "day: 453 isLeapMonth: false ". How to get just number from this?

Comment: @ifF3 I think components.day should give the integer.