# How to hide Time from date string Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, date-formatting

I have the string:

**1980-02-17T04:00:00.000Z**

I want to remove all text after "T" in:

```
Text(user.DOB)
```

How would I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, `user.DOB` is a `String`? And not a `Date`?

Comment: It is a Date value returned from MongoDB

Comment: `Text(user.DOB, style: .date)`

Comment: So, judging by your edit, it *is* in fact a `String`?

Comment: Yea I made a mistake and couldn't make another question so edited it. My bad,  thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not particularly sophisticated, you could simply go for

```
Text(user.DOB.prefix(10))
```

It lets you keep MongoDB's format for elsewhere in your app if you end up needing it.

Comment: I would assume that's already been considered by MongoDB when it produced the string. The question only asked how to remove a portion of the String.

Comment: From the UX perspective, this is a totally wrong answer.

Comment: @Alexander it’s the exact answer he asked for

Comment: That's why I said "From the UX perspective...". Your answer to OP's question is correct in a narrow sense, but OP is asking the wrong question, and you're accidentally further guiding him down his wrong direction by not letting him know that passing an ISO 8601 formatted string to a `Text` is really suspitious

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 (formatting a date object):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-dd"
let monthString = dateFormatter.string(from: user.DOB)
```

where:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-dd"
```

represents the format of date you want

If you don't have a date object you can get one from your string:

```
  formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

  let parsedDate = formatter.dateFromString(date)
```

Option 2(formating a date string):

```
let parsedDate = date.prefix(10)
```

Comment: Use `date(from:)` instead of `dateFromString`

Comment: Also be aware that without setting the time zone to UTC for the second date formatter might produce a different date than expected for the users current time zone.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1980-02-17T04:00:00.000Z"
if let index = str.firstIndex(of: "T") {
    let a = str.substring(to: index)
    print(a) // Prints 1980-02-17
}
```

Considering you don't want T in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just:

```swift
var dateStringWithoutT = "1980-02-17T04:00:00.000Z"
                              .split(separator: "T")
                              .first
```

What the above code does is, split the string by "T" and you get `["1980-02-17","04:00:00.000Z"]`, then, use array's `first` property to get what you need.

Complexity: O(n)