# How can you format a kotlinx-datetime LocalDateTime?

Tags: android, kotlin, localdatetime, kotlinx-datetime

I'm converting some code from using Java 8's `LocalDatetime` to using the version from `kotlinx-datetime` and I can't find any formatting methods. Specifically, I'm replacing a `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`. Do they not exist and I need to write the formatting?

This is for an Android app. Is there are there Android specific libraries I can use? Or can I do this with pre-Java 8 methods to maintain support for older versions of Android?

**Edit (my solution based on the answer from Arvind)**:

```kotlin
fun Instant.toDateTimeString(formatStyle: FormatStyle = FormatStyle.MEDIUM): String {
    val localDatetime = toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault())
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(formatStyle)
    return formatter.format(localDatetime.toJavaLocalDateTime())
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime#implementation), in a JVM, the implementation of date/time types, such as `Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, `TimeZone` and so on, relies on `java.time` API. It also natively supports [ThreeTen backport project](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) using which you can backport most of the `java.time` functionality to Java 6 & 7. Check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/10819573) to learn how to set it up.

In case you want to replace an OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) format e.g `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`, you can always define a custom format using `DateTimeFormatter` e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.MEDIUM);

        // Custom equivalent format with a fixed Locale
        DateTimeFormatter dtfCustom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM uuuu, HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();

        System.out.println(ldt.format(dtf));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(dtfCustom));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
6 Nov 2021, 12:18:26
6 Nov 2021, 12:18:26
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GAr8mj)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I missed that part of the docs. So I guess I'll use the Java 8 API with desugaring and add an implementation with Joda time when/if we support a JS target.

Comment: I'm targeting iOS also so I can't rely on the JVM, is there any other way of formatting?

Comment: @KenIchi,  I do not have experience in iOS but looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35700281/10819573), it looks like Java's way of formatting/parsing date-time is mostly the same in iOS.