# iOS-Swift How to convert a String of Date to another String of Date

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have this String "Aug 15, 2022". How can I convert it to "Monday, August 15, 2022"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Format in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already tried what you gave, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//First u have to convert ur date to a Date object
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "MM dd, yy"
dateFormatterGet.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "Aug 15, 2022")

//Next crate a formatter that gives u the desired output
let dateFormatterSet = DateFormatter()
//EEEE -> for the day name -> in your case Monday
//MMMM -> for the full month name (if u use MM it will give u 'Aug`)
dateFormatterSet.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"
let updatedDate = dateFormatterSet.string(from: date!)

print(updatedDate) // -> Monday, August 15, 2022
```