# Decoding date value from a json and show it as custom string date format in swiftUI

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

I'm trying to decode a json that has date value inside the json is like this

```
{
 "id": 2
 "startDate": "2022-08-01T18:44:09.538",
 "endDate": "2023-07-30T03:03:56.249",
 "dateCreated": "2022-07-30T03:05:08.8338403" 
}
```

and here is my struct model for the Json.

```
struct JsonResponse: Decodable, Identifiable {
 var id: Int
 var startDate: Date
 var endDate: Date
 var dateCreated: Date
}
```

My question is how can I decode these dates and show them in a Text() like "**Mon 11/22**" format. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `iso8601` date decoding strategy doesn't support milliseconds, so you have to add a custom date decoding strategy to decode the string as `Date`. Or to do the bidirectional conversion implement `int(from decoder`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can decode this. If you want to **convert String** to **Date**. You can try this:

```
func getDate(fromDate: String) -> Date {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d yyyy"
        let date = formatter.date(from: fromDate)!
        
        return date
    }
```

And if you want to convert **Date** into **String**. You can try this:

```
func getString(from date: Date) -> String {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d yyyy"
        let strDate = formatter.string(from: date)
        return strDate
    }
```

And if you want to convert **String** to **String**:

```
func getStringFrom(strDate: String) -> String {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        let date = formatter.date(from: strDate) ?? Date()

        let outformatter = DateFormatter()
        outformatter.dateFormat = "MMM d yyyy"
        return outformatter.string(from: date)
    }
```

You can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700281/date-format-in-swift) for the **date formats**.